# Find the area of the circle circumscribed to a $\triangle ABC$, below.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Calculate the area of the circle circumscribed to a $\triangle ABC$, such that $AB=BC$, $AC=6$ and measure of angle $ABC =37^o$ (S:$25 \pi$)

Is it possible to solve without using a calculator?

[image]

Comment: But the circumradius $\frac {3}{\sin 37^\circ}$ is not exactly $5$.

Comment: Agree with @peterwhy - the solution is not $25\pi$.

Comment: @peterwhy I believe the answer is approximate

Comment: Would a resolution by geometry be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let your $H$ be placed at $(0,0)$ and your $C$ be placed at $(3,0)$.

Using the 'Angle at center theorem' which states that $2\angle ABC=\angle AOC$, we know then that point $O$ is located at $\left(0,\frac{3}{\tan(37°)}\right)$.

This gives a distance $OC=R=\sqrt{9+\left(\frac{3}{\tan(37°)}\right)^2}=\frac{3}{\sin(37°)}$ which is roughly $R\approx 4.98492$.

The circle's area, with $a=R^2π$, is then
$a\approx 24,85π$.

---

As for figuring this out without a calculator, best would probably be to use the Taylor series for $(\sin)$ in radians:$$\sin(x) = x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}- ...$$  This is doable - as well as a strong point towards using a calculator.

Comment: thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

One can get the circumradius at once, using the (extended) law of sines (see [here](https://www.geogebra.org/m/ycbWy8C9)):

$$\frac{a}{\sin(A)}=2R$$

one gets :

$$R=\frac{a}{2 \sin(A)}$$

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is probably a Peruvian question and being so, they use the relationship between sides and angles of the right triangle a lot.$\triangle (37^o : 53^o : 90^o) \implies (3k:4k:5k)\\
\angle AEC_{(inscribed)} \implies \angle AOC_{central)} = 2.\angle AEC = 74^o \\
\therefore \angle HOC =37^o : \angle OCH = 63^ o \\
\triangle HOC: CH=3k = 3\implies k =1\\
\therefore R = 5k =5 \implies S = \pi R^2 = 5^2 \pi = \boxed{25 \pi}$